# Unable to display the div with php code through ajax in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

I am new in ajax.I am trying to display specific restaurant data when selected the area from drop down via ajax but i am not able to display the restaurant view correctly Please guide me what i do.

Please guide me how can i embed view code in controller

Its view code:

```
     <div class="container">


            <table align="centre" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover no-margin"style="width:70%">
           <thead>
           <tr style="width: 56%;">
               <th>
                   No.    
               </th>
               <th style="">
                Restaurant Names
               </th>
           </tr>

           </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php $i=1;foreach($result as $row){
                ?>
            <tr id="<?php echo $row->restaurant_id; ?>" class="res_id">
                <th style="">
                    <?php echo  $i++; ?>
                </th>
                <th style="">
                    <?php echo $row->restaurant_name; ?>

                </th>

                <th style="width: 1%" >
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/BulkRecipe_Controller/bulk_recipe/<?php echo $row->restaurant_id;?>"  class="btn btn-warning" <i class="glyphicon-edit"></i>See Menu</a>

                </th>
                 </tr>
            <?php } ?>

            </tbody>
            </table>
</div>
```

Its controller code:

```
 public function get_rests()
    {
        $cit_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $area = $this->uri->segment(4);
        $where = array('city_id'=>$cit_id,'city_area_id'=>$area);
        $fetchdetail = $this->bulk->select_record('restaurant',$where);

}
```

Ajax code:

```
    function get_rests(){

    var city_id = $('#city_id').val();
    var area_id = $("#area_id").val();
    $.getJSON("<?= base_url();?>index.php/Bulk_Controller/get_rests/"+city_id+"/"+area_id,function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function(i, j){

            $('#restAgainst').append("<div>"+j.restaurant_name+"</div>");
        });

    });
}
```

Model code:

```
function select_record($table, $where = NULL){

    $this->db->select();
    if($where)
        $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->from($table);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

View code:

```
        <div id="restAgainst">

    </div>
```

Comment: cannot see the ajax function being called?is there any result on your console once selected?

Comment: Read this http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-edit-delete-and-update-data-without-refreshing-page-in-codeigniter/

Comment: is `restAgainst` present in same view?? Both view code should be present in same page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

View:(inside javascript)

```
var city_id = $('#city_id').val();
var area_id = $("#area_id").val();
  getRequest("<?= base_url();?>index.php/Bulk_Controller/get_rests/"+city_id+"/"+area_id", function(data) {

    var data = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        $("#name").append("<span>" +data[i].restaurant_name+ "</span>");

    }
});


  function getRequest(url, callback) {
    var request;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest(); // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    } else {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // IE6, IE5
    }
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            callback(request);
            $('.loading').hide();
        }
    }
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.send();
}
```

Controller:

```
public function name()
{

    $this->load->model('page_model');

    $name= $this->page_model->name();

    echo json_encode($name);
}
```

Model:

```
public function name()
{
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tname');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();

    return $result;
}
```